# Create class instance from plain object without manual constructor

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create a class instance from a plain object without manually mapping plain object values to class instance variables?

For example:

```
class Person {
  id;
  firstName;
  lastName;
  age;

  fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
}

const hemmingway = {
  id: 1,
  firstName: "Ernest",
  lastName: "Hemmingway",
  age: 62
};
```

Is it possible to create a `Person` class instance out of `hemmingway` without having to resort to manually mapping the keys like this:

```
constructor(plainObject) {
      this.id = plainObject.id;
      this.firstName = plainObject.lastName;
      this.lastName = plainObject.lastName;
      this.age = plainObject.age;
}
```

This would be extremely helpful when trying to map network API response objects to class instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After passing the object, use `Object.assign` to assign all of its properties to the instantiation:

```js
class Person {
  id;
  firstName;
  lastName;
  age;
  constructor(plainObject) {
    Object.assign(this, plainObject);
  }
  fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
}

const hemmingway = {
  id: 1,
  firstName: "Ernest",
  lastName: "Hemmingway",
  age: 62
};
const personHemmingway = new Person(hemmingway);
console.log(personHemmingway.fullName());
```

Of course, you could also do it outside of the constructor:

```js
class Person {
  id;
  firstName;
  lastName;
  age;
  fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
}

const hemmingway = {
  id: 1,
  firstName: "Ernest",
  lastName: "Hemmingway",
  age: 62
};
const personHemmingway = new Person();
Object.assign(personHemmingway, hemmingway);
console.log(personHemmingway.fullName());
```